# FileNotFoundException Using HandlebarsTemplateEngine with Sparkjava

Tags: java, spark-java, handlebars.java

I have a problem with spark.
I am trying to load a view "base.hbs" but whenever i try to load it spark throws an FileNotFoundException

I tried changing the constructor to new HandlebarsTemplateEngine("tried/different/paths/here"); but no luck. I even tried putting resources folder in C:/ Drive and loading it externally but still no luck...

I am not using the regular embedded Jetty Server, But I am using a tomcat server... I can assure you that other get methods work(Where i return a string)

Much help appreciated thank you.

Code:

```
@Override
public void init() {

    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("name", "Sam Cooke");

    get("/hello", (rq, rs) -> {
        System.out.println(rq.contextPath());

        return new ModelAndView(map, "base.hbs");}, new HandlebarsTemplateEngine("resources/templates/"));

    exception(Exception.class, (ex, rq, rs)->{ex.printStackTrace();});
}
```

Folder Structure:

[image: File Structure]

Exception:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/templates/base.hbs
at spark.template.handlebars.HandlebarsTemplateEngine.render(HandlebarsTemplateEngine.java:78)
at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl$1.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:61)
at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl$1.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:58)
at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:85)
at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:62)
at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:126)
at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.doFilter(SparkFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/templates/base.hbs
at com.github.jknack.handlebars.io.URLTemplateLoader.sourceAt(URLTemplateLoader.java:70)
at com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compile(Handlebars.java:391)
at com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compile(Handlebars.java:377)
at spark.template.handlebars.HandlebarsTemplateEngine.render(HandlebarsTemplateEngine.java:75)
... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the answer was to restart eclipse... Jesus this was a day of bugs solved with a restart... thanks clipse...